# Casting of hierarichally overrided method - Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a code snippet:

```java
class A {
    public String f(A obj) { return ("A & A");}
    public String f(D obj) { return ("A & D");}
}

class B extends A {
    public String f(A obj) { return ("B & A");}
    public String f(B obj) { return ("B & B");}
}

class C extends B{
}

class D extends B{
}

class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new B();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        D d = new D();
        System.out.println(a1.f(b));
        System.out.println(a1.f(c));
        System.out.println(a1.f(d));
        System.out.println(a2.f(b));
        System.out.println(a2.f(c));
        System.out.println(a2.f(d));
        System.out.println(b.f(b));
        System.out.println(b.f(c));
        System.out.println(b.f(d));
    }
}
```

The answer is:

```
A & A
A & A
A & D
B & A
B & A
A & D
B & B
B & B
A & D
```

But I don't understand why starting from `a2.f(b)`. Can someone explain me the logic behind these ? Because there is casting of hierirchally overrided method and I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point you are missing is the contract between *overriding* and *overloading*. They are entirely different.

### Overriding

```
class A {
  void foo() { System.out.println("A"); }
}

class B extends A {
  void foo() { System.out.println("B"); }
}

void main() {
  A a1 = new A();
  a1.foo();
  A a2 = new B();
  a2.foo();
}
```

B's `foo()` definition *overrides* A's foo definition. It does that because its name **and** its parameter types (both 'no parameters' here) are entirely identical to A's. Java uses dynamic dispatch to do overriding, in other words, the above code prints 'A', then 'B'. Even though the `a2` variable type is `A`, the object that this variable is actually pointing at (in java slang, 'referencing' - just another word for pointer) is of type B, and due to dynamic dispatch rules, B's foo() is invoked.

Note that the signatures have to match *exactly* for overriding to apply. You can ask the compiler to verify that you are overriding something using the `@Override` annotation. This annotation does nothing (not having it doesn't mean it isn't an override), unless the method doesn't override anything, in which case `javac` will error out when you attempt to compile it. Consider it compiler-checked documentation.

### Overloading

If the method signature does not *match precisely*, then as far as java is concerned, they are 2 **utterly unrelated methods**. In java terminology, that is called an *overload*. Not an *override*:

```
class A {
  void foo(String a) {System.out.println("String"); }
  void foo(Object a) {System.out.println("Object"): }
}

void main() {
  String x = "";
  foo(x);
  Object y = "";
  foo(y);
}
```

Unlike overrides, overloads are *statically dispatched*. Meaning, the actual type of the thing is immaterial, it's about the type of the expression at compile time.  Thus, even though both `x` and `y` are pointing at strings, the above prints `String` and then `Object`, because `y` (the variable itself, not the object it points at) is of type `Object`.

### Explaining your snippet

You've got a weird combo of overrides and overloads. Specifically,

B's `f(A obj)` is an *override* - it overrides A's `f(A obj)`. However, B's `f(D obj)` is an *overload* - it doesn't override anything. If you slap a `@Override` annotation on there, it would produce a compiler error. Hence, B, the type, has 3 **completely unrelated** methods:

- foo(A)
- foo(B)
- foo(C)

Which implementation ends up being used is not something javac cares about, that's java's (the runtime)'s problem. Javac just figures out which of the 3 methods is meant, and writes that into the produced class file. Java.exe will figure out from the receiver's *actual type* (the `z` in `z.foo(x)` is called the 'received') which implementation to invoke).

Thus:

```java
System.out.println(a2.f(b));
```

The compiler goes:

`a2` is of type `A` (that it is at runtime actually pointing at an instance of B is immaterial here, we're still compiling, we're not running anything yet). A has 2 methods, both named foo: `foo(A)` and `foo(D)`.

You are passing an expression to it of type `B`. Given that B is not a D, But all Bs are As, clearlyt then you meant `foo(A)`, and javac will dutifully encode a call to `A::foo(A)` into the class file.

At runtime, java sees this, checks the actual receiver's type which ends up being an instance of B, and calls B's override of `foo(A)`, which prints B & A.

---

```java
System.out.println(a2.f(c));
```

Explanation is identical.

---

```java
        System.out.println(a2.f(d));
```

Ah, now, the compiler can tell: `d`, the variable (not the object it points at) is of type `D`, therefore, the compiler writes this into the class file as a call to `A::foo(d)`. At runtime, You get `A & D`, because whilst the object `a2` points at is of type `B`, B has not overridden foo's `foo(D)` method.

---

Using the same logic, you can explain every answer. I'll leave the rest as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Good explanation, although a small mistake in B's println method. I think you wanted to print "B" instead of "A"

Comment: I've learned a lot from your post, sincerely thanks. Especially about dynamic dispatch, statical dispatch and the role of `javac` and `java` commands.

Comment: @noev well spotted; I have fixed the answer.